# Writing to aux - you can't use a prefix with `the character @'

Tags: macros, labels, auxiliary-files

In a previous project, we used the following macro to define requirements, so that they were easy to reference later in the text.

```
\newcommand{\reqlabel}[2]{%
  \label{#1}
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string \newlabel {#1_long}{{\ref{#1} (#2)}{\thepage}{#2}{#1}{}}}
\hypertarget{#1}{#2}
}
```

I copied this into a new preamble for a different project, and i cannot get it working now.

I am getting the following error:

```
! You can't use a prefix with `the character @'.
```

I tried to use write instead of protected write, which gives another error:

```
! Improper \spacefactor.
\@->\spacefactor 
             \@m
```

Comment: You  forgot `\makeatletter`.

Comment: Undoubtedly, Ulrike's comment is right on the money, but, in the future, try to include a minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), whenever appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@` is not a letter, which can be used in command names. It can be used in class and package files, where `@` has category code letter.
Otherwise `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` can be used to change the category code:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reqlabel}[2]{%
  \label{#1}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string \newlabel {#1_long}{{\string\ref{#1} (#2)}{\thepage}{#2}{#1}{}}}%
  \hypertarget{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

The purpose of `\reqlabel` is not clear to me, maybe you want the star for of `\ref` in the label to avoid nested links. Also I have commented the line ends to avoid unwanted spaces.

Comment: Then you very much! I've spend a good 2 hours trying to figure out what was going on!

There properly is a easier and more secure way to accomplish the same, but none of us are that well endeavored in LaTeX.

Comment: @lbromo TeX.sx can also be used for "non-trivial" questions. ☺